# (Hidden?) MS Visual Studio settings affecting C/C++ compilation

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, mfc

I have a C++ file that compiles fine in one project, but not in another. The file is the exact same C++ file in both projects.

Both projects are MFC dialog-based projects. They have slightly different stdafx.h files... but if I'm prepared to break the rest of the project, I can make them identical... and still get this compiler error. Equally, they have considerably different include paths, but if I break even more of the project and make the include paths identical, I still get the error. It goes without saying that I have made all my preprocessor directives identical... and I still get the error.

So, as far as I can tell, I'm down to compiler switches. I've made them identical (within reason - I haven't bothered to change the `/Fp`, `/Fd` or `/Fo` output files), but still it refuses to compile. Are there any "hidden" settings or anything else that might be affecting compilation?

[Note: the following is included mostly for historical reasons - it led to an unintentional over-emphasis when this question was originally posed, and so led to predictable comments and answers which didn't help resolve the intended "when is identical not identical?" question]

The error itself is error 2894 (templates cannot have 'C' linkage). I understand this error, but not how/why it is occurring. It occurs within a bunch of C header files pertaining to a C library. They are all neatly wrapped in `extern "C" {...}` declarations, with `#ifdef __cplusplus` correctly applied. But `extern C {...}` is not something I'm very familiar with, so... is there anything special about `extern "C" {...}` that might be a factor?

Comment: My guess, and given the information, it can only be a guess, is that you are including a C++ header file into a file with a .c extension, and the compiler is compiling the code as "C" rather than "C++", and the error is not directly because of `extern "C" { ... }` in itself - but it could also be that you are including a C++ header within a `extern "C" { ... }` block. The only good way to solve this sort of problem is to start cutting down on the code you compile until you have a few dozen lines or so, at which point it's typically very obvious.

Comment: Make a copy of the broken project and start reducing it down to the minimal size to produce the error. Ideally you will get the source code down to a single cpp file that #includes the wspapi.h header. Then start reducing the projects options.

Comment: Did you try Googling `extern "C"`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson - the single file is a .cpp file, and is identical in both projects. Moreover, I've cut the code back to 3 lines - the inclusion of three header files (which go on to include other) and the difference is still not obvious. But I would focus on the difference, not the `extern "C"`, because in the end, the C compiler is invoked in one condition which works, and another which doesn't, and it is invoked ignorant of everything else in the project, is it not?

Comment: Well, then start cutting down on what is being included, until you only have a dozen lines in the include files... I'd be very surprised if it's not VERY obvious once you get there...

Comment: Showing the code and the compiler log verbatim would be far easier and more accurate than *describing* it.

Comment: Found it after 24 hours of frustration - see answer below - my previous googling had not shown up the `showIncludes` compiler option... which was extremely illuminating

Answer (score 1):

If a single C++ file is compiled under the same conditions, it leads to the same result. It doesn't matter if it is in a project with zero other files, or a hundred other files - the compiler compiles each file individually.

Therefore, if a single C++ file compiles with different results, then that is either because:

- It is not really the same single C++ file, or
- It is not really the same compilation conditions.

You can see exactly what the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler thinks your "single" C++ file truly is by specifying `/showIncludes` as an "advanced" compiler option. You might be surprised to see how different your "identical" C++ file is (and this was the case here).

Equally, you can see the explicit C++ compiler conditions listed under the `Command Line` summary that appears at the bottom of the list of `C/C++` options in the project properties in Visual Studio.

Comment: So was your question about how to find the options applied to the compiler or how to fix your problem? This does not answer he latter, and it does not indicate how this information might help you solve the problem.  Looks like an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem to me

Comment: @Clifford Apologies if it bordered on an XY problem... so I'm actually going to edit the question, because I think it is a useful one despite the downvotes.

Comment: I don't think this is an XY problem (hence why I gave your original question its first upvote), but it *does* seem that you are trying to over-generalize both the problem and the solution past the point of usefulness. If you were compiling the same file with the same include path and the same compiler switches, why was the list of include files different?

Answer (score 0):

wspapi.h includes some C++ template code outside of its internal `extern "C"` section.  If you were to externally wrap the header in an `extern "C"` declaration, you would break it.

For example, you cannot do this:

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <wspapi.h>
}
```

Similarly, if a preceding header or code has failed to terminate an `extern "C"` block so that all the content of the header is given C linkage, the same situation arises.

Put simply, wpsapi.h has been included within a C linkage block, it has nothing to do with "hidden options".

Comment: Nice - wouldn't have solved my particular issue, but useful to know.

Comment: @omatai : you are not being very enlightening, and therefore this is not a good SO Q&A.  The compiler error arises when template code is included while `extern "C"` is active, so I'd be amazed if this was not the cause - even if the mechanism is not identical to the example code fragment.

Comment: Maybe someone could have written it better... but I guess the question is "how can identical things lead to different results?" It happens to involve `extern "C"`, but it could have involved `aardvarks`. I can't stop people focusing on the extraneous symptoms, but I felt I had to mention it (kept it out of the title; mentioned it only at the end) so as to suggest that I'd actually done some research into what the specific error meant. I ask questions to try to enlighten - if this saves someone that 24 hours it frustrated me, that's surely what SO is for, isn't it?